# how can i rotate the text in flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

in my application I need to create a tile where the number is rotated. For example instead of having this orientation

[image]

I have this orientation

[image]

Can anyone help me?
thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 1,
      child: new Text("I AM ROTATING ONE")
    )
```